# Discord.py Cogs : Extension is not defined

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Hi in my code for a Python Discord bot i started to try some Cogs. But somehow when I run the code i get the Error that Extension is not defined but in the Toturial i watched he never defined Extension.

```
extensions = ['cogs.postgres']
if __name__ == "__main__":
    for extensions in extensions:
        try:
            bot.load_extension(extension)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Error loading {extension}', file=sys.stderr)
            traceback.print_exc()
```

The Exact Error is : "NameError: name 'extension' is not defined"
Can someone help me?I googled that error but did not found anything to cogs Extensions is not defined.

Comment: This is a typo: You do `for extensions in extensions` instead of `for extension in extensions`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're in fact not defining extension, fix:

```py
for extension in extensions:
```

I think you simply miscopied

Comment: Why do get this Questions so many downvotes? Cant a Miss spelling hapening to everyone?

Comment: It can happen, but typically people don’t ask questions like that on SO, it’d take you a couple of minutes to figure it out by yourself

Answer (score 0):

You've accidentally mis-spelt your variable `extension` when you're supposed to do `for extension in extensions:`